# array_key_exists not working as expected

Tags: php, array-key-exists

## Problem

I'm having trouble  using the PHP function `array_key_exists`. Even though my array has the key, the function always returns false. I wonder if there is a issue regards using a dynamically growing array. I'm new to PHP, sorry if the question is annoying trivial.

## Expected behavior

I need the `array_key_exists` function returning true if the array has the key.

## What I tried to solve

I tried to use `isset(CounterArray[$key])` instead but I got no success.

I've already read the PHP docs, for the specific function and I've also checked similar questions on stack-overflow but none of them were suitable for my case. I'm 
shamefully expending a huge time with this.

## code

```
$values=[
        "a"=>100,
        "a"=>100,
        "a"=>100,
        "b"=>200,   
    ];


    $counterArray = array();

    foreach ($values as $key => $price) {

        if(!array_key_exists( $key , $counterArray))){
            $counterArray[$key]=$price;

        }else{

            $counterArray[$key] += $price;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't have array `$values` with same key `a` used 3 times and therefore there is no condition on this script where `array_key_exists()` should return `true`.

Comment: You need to change the the array to what you actually have. We can't answer the question if we don't know what your array looks like. Preferably post the real array with var_export or json_encode. There may be faster methods that looping if we only get to see the real array.

Comment: OMG I'm so dumb !!! I need to stop coding overtime. Thank you @Havenard

Answer (score 2):

Your `$values` array contains duplicates of the same key `'a'`, which will be ignored. Thus, `$counter_array` will end up containing an exact copy of `$values`.

It sounds like `$values` should be an array of arrays, e.g.:

```
$values = [
    ["a"=>100],
    ["a"=>100],
    ["a"=>100],
    ["b"=>200],
];
```

Of course, your loop will have to change accordingly:

```
foreach ($values as $a) {
    list( $key, $price ) = $a;
    // ...
```

Comment: You are right. I was so distracted. I hope my teachers don't see it !!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your actual array is internally like
array(2) { ["a"]=> int(100) ["b"]=> int(200) 
You will get above output when you do
var_dump($values);
In your code